# ](1 of 2)A start job is running to Set the console keyboard layout

Tags: kernel, keyboard-layout, udev

What does this mean in Ubuntu - lastest. Just installed video card, booted up, and this has been running for some time:
](1 of 2)A start job is running to Set the console keyboard layout
and
](2 of 2)A start job is running for udev kernel device manager
[FAILED]Failed to start udev kernel device manager
This and other text keeps cycling - What can I do to change this action so I can access Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you able to login from recovery mode? Reboot, Press Shift to get  grub menu, select advanced then recovery mode.